# grails-bootstrap-file-upload plugin error

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'am trying to implement bootstrap file upload plugin in my currrent project and and i'm getting this following error.while all the .js and .css files are present in web-app but after that also this error is coming..

Note -- grails version 2.4.0

Error msg

```
Error |
2014-07-14 18:34:15,132 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  -Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-image-gallery.css

Error |
2014-07-14 18:34:15,212 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  -Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-image-gallery.js

Error |
2014-07-14 18:34:15,366 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  -Resource not found: /assets/tmpl.js

Error |
2014-07-14 18:34:15,441 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  -Resource not found: /assets/load-image.js

Error |
2014-07-14 18:34:15,528 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  -Resource not found: /assets/canvas-to-blob.js

Error |
2014-07-14 18:34:15,568 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  -Resource not found: /assets/jquery.fileupload-ui.css

Error |
2014-07-14 18:34:15,609 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  -Resource not found: /assets/jquery.iframe-transport.js

Error |
2014-07-14 18:34:15,649 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  -Resource not found: /assets/jquery.fileupload.js

Error |
2014-07-14 18:34:15,689 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  -Resource not found: /assets/jquery.fileupload-ip.js

Error |
2014-07-14 18:34:15,796 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  -Resource not found: /assets/jquery.fileupload-ui.js
```

Comment: Are you using the asset-pipeline plugin?

Comment: Yes!! asset-pipeline:1.8.7 this is in my build.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the asset pipeline plugin, I'm assuming that you're using the `<asset:javascript />` tag to render the scripts. In that case, you need to place your javascript in an `assets` folder in your `grails-app`.

Or you can change your configuration for picking up your resources from the "/" context in `Config.groovy`.

Check out the documentation for asset pipeline to know about more options.

http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/